# How to use the library exported from FunctionCompileExportLibrary outside of Mathematic (e.g., in Visual Studio)?

Tags: external-calls, version-12, compiler

Mathematica 12 has a new function `FunctionCompileExportLibrary`, which can export a pure function as a `.dll` file like this:

```
FunctionCompileExportLibrary["function.dll", Function[
   Typed[arg, "MachineInteger"], arg + 1]]
```

> `"...\\function.dll"`

But how to call it in an external program (e.g., visual studio)? I have no `.h` file, I have no `.lib` file. I even don't know the function name that I want to call... Can anyone tell me how to use it?

The documentation of [`FunctionCompileExportLibrary`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionCompileExportLibrary.html) states that

> The library generated by FunctionCompileExportLibrary is suitable for linking into external programs. It can also be loaded into the Wolfram System using LibraryFunctionLoad.

Comment: Could you try something like what is done [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/using-run-time-dynamic-linking)?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I have look your link, but I'm not good at it. Could you please give an example to use it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a quick example of calling the exported compiled function from a standalone executable on Windows.

A few things to note which are currently undocumented and that can definitely be subject to change (and improvement) in the future:

- the function is named `Main` by default and the example uses an explicit prototype rather than including a header file;
- the Wolfram Runtime Library is linked statically for convenience (of course, the dynamic WolframRTL.dll could be used instead provided the executable can find it);
- `CreateExecutable` is also used for convenience here, however the test executable could be compiled in any other way;
- while the Windows import library (`function.lib`) is created, currently it is not placed next to the DLL. I expect this will be corrected in a paclet update.

  ```
  lib = FunctionCompileExportLibrary["function.dll",
            Function[Typed[arg, "MachineInteger"], arg + 1], 
             "CompilerOptions" -> "CreateLibraryOptions" -> 
                {"SystemLibraries" -> {"WolframRTL_Static_Minimal"}}];

  Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

  test = CreateExecutable["
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <inttypes.h>
     int64_t Main(int64_t);
     int main() {
        printf(\"%\" PRId64, Main(10));
     }", 
     "test", "Libraries" -> {FileNameJoin[{$CCompilerDefaultDirectory, "function.lib"}]}];

  RunProcess[test, "StandardOutput"]

  (* "11" *)
  ```

---

Regarding the follow-up question in the [edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/195432/8): I think the linker is looking for the C++ mangled name. Try declaring `Main` with C linkage, i.e. `extern "C"`. Also make sure the prototype is using the correct integer type.

Comment: Fun, would mind to tell me how to know the name is 'Main'? It's seem not very explicit...

Comment: One way is to look at e.g. `LibraryFunctionLoad[lib] // InputForm`

Comment: it is also discoverable by using `nm -gU library.dylib` under macOS.

Comment: This is quite promising! I am curious about other valid settings in `"CompilerOptions"`, which seem to make this function more powerful! However, this is heavily undocumented...

Comment: This method does not work on osx, got `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/function.dylib
  Referenced from: ...
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6` on the generated executable.

Comment: @happyfish Yes, I'm using the Windows feature of looking for DLLs next to the executable. This can be made to work on Mac too, but it would need setting some rpaths and/or copying over some additional .dylibs.

Comment: What if the input or the output is an array? What would be the prototype of `Main`, and is this documented somewhere? Is it an MTensor or MNumericArray?

Comment: No, definitely not documented. MTensor and MNumericArray have the same underlying representation.

Comment: It's seem the name alway is `Main`. If we export two function into a `.dll`. How to call those? And can we export a noramal function(not pure function) now? Can we put two or more function into a `.dll` file?

Comment: I make a note for your answer in following answer but I don't get any reputation. Hope you don't mind the behavior. All honor should belong to you.

Comment: @happy fish, you can solve the library path issues by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the process environment: `RunProcess[test, 
 ProcessEnvironment -> <| 
   "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> 
    "/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Libraries/MacOSX-x86-64:" <> $CCompilerDefaultDirectory|>]`. This works, but I'm now getting a segmentation fault each time I try to use a Kernel function.

Answer (score 5):

As the ilian's answer, I make a note for Visual Studio user here to supplement:

**source.cpp file**

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" int Main(int);
int main() {
    cout << Main(3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

configure Visual Studio

1. In **Configuration Properties/Debugging/Environment** add

> PATH=C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\12.0en\SystemFiles\Kernel\Binaries\Windows-x86-64;%appdata%\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64;C:\Program
>   Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\12.0en\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64

The first directory has some [necessary .dll file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaKqN.png). The second and the three directory have `function.dll` and `WolframRTL.dll` respectively. Of course, your can don't set the `PATH` evironment if you copy all those `.dll` file into the direcotry with `source.cpp` or the `Configuration Properties/Output Directory`.

2. In **Configuration Properties/VC++ Directories/Library Directories** add

> %appdata%\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64

This directory include `function.lib`

3. In **Configuration Properties/Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies** add

> function.lib

Then you can run the c++ project now. I think this is a small step for Wolframer, but a giant leap for those men who hope to use Mathematica in his work.

Answer (score 4):

This is a follow-up of [@ilian's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/195557/260), which doesn't work under macOS but provides a promising basis.

The error reported by [@happy fish](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195432/how-to-use-the-library-exported-from-functioncompileexportlibrary-outside-of-mat#comment508843_195557) that `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/function.dylib Referenced from: ... Reason: image not found Abort trap: 6` suggests the linking was not correct. Then I tried to correct the @rpath issue (which seems to be a bug but I'm not quite sure; this needs further investigation) and still got other linking issues which clearly indicated `libWolframRTL_Static_Minimal.a` was not statically linked (which is [a well-known pain on macOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1118/_index.html)).

So below I provide a workaround for macOS, which used the `FunctionCompileExport` instead of `FunctionCompileExportLibrary` due to possible linking bug in it:

```
pathStaticLib="/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Libraries/MacOSX-x86-64/libWolframRTL_Static_Minimal.a";
lib=FunctionCompileExport["function.o",Function[Typed[arg,"MachineInteger"],arg+1];

Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

test=CreateExecutable["
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <inttypes.h>
   int64_t Main(int64_t);
   int main() {
      printf(\"%\" PRId64, Main(10));
   }","test","CompileOptions"->pathStaticLib,"ExtraObjectFiles"->{lib}];

RunProcess[test]

(*<|"ExitCode"->0,"StandardOutput"->"11","StandardError"->""|>*)
```

Comment: This doesn't compile as soon as you try to use a Kernel function.